# C++ resources allocation with multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, boost-thread

I have got a small application and I am using some library via API. This library uses multithreading and I can't figure out how to properly allocate memory.

Let's say I have a class `MyClass`. This class have a function `myFunction` and a pointer `ptrToSomething`. In class's constructor I dynamically create an object (not read-only) and assign it to `ptrToSomething`, then I work with it in `myFunction`. And there's only one instance of this class.

With single thread it works fine. But the library I use may call `myFunction` in different threads. Which means `ptrToSomething` must be unique for each thread. Oh, and this library uses `boost::thread`.

So, here's what I do:

1. I create an array `ptrArray` of length `n` (for `n` threads) and initialize it with objects in the constructor.
2. Create `boost:mutex` inside `MyClass`.
3. Create `std::set<boost::thread::id> idSet` for threads ids.

Now in `myFunction` I lock the mutex, find out the current thread's id with `boost::this_thread::get_id()`, insert it into `idSet`, find it's index with `std::set::find` and `std::distance`, assign the proper `ptrToSomething[idx]` to some temp pointer, unlock the mutex and continue with the function.

This code sure works, but I feel it is **very inefficient**.

Is there a more optimal approach? Or maybe some kind of modifications on the current one?

UPD. Something like this.

```
class MyClass : public SomeLibraryClass
{
  public:
    MyObject* ptrToSomething;
    mutable std::set<boost::thread::id> threadsIds;
    mutable boost::mutex mutex;

    MyClass(){
        ptrToSomething = new MyObject[threadsNumber];

        for(int i = 0; i < threadsNumber; ++i){
            ptrToSomething[i] = new MyObject();
        }
    }

    void myFunction() const override{
        {
            boost::thread::id id = boost::this_thread::get_id();
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(mutex);
            threadsIds.insert(id);
            std::set<boost::thread::id>::iterator iter = threadsIds.find(id);
            int index = std::distance(threadsIds.begin(), iter);
            myTempObject = &ptrToSomething[index];
        }

        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't describe your code.  Show your code in the question.

Comment: This description sounds complex and unusual. Could you provide some discussion of the design decisions and why they were chosen? I don't understand the reason for the `ptrToSomething[]` array. Its as if you have tried to have a monolithic, centralized architecture for an application whose nature is inherently de-centralized and distributed and are trying to shoehorn centralized control over what should be a much lighter, distributed architecture.

Comment: @RichardChambers This class I am writing is an extension or plugin. Usually `myFunction` is a small almost "inline" function. But I am trying to extend the library for a pretty complex entity that loads lots of stuff in the constructor and allocates lots of memory.

Comment: Why do different threads each need their own personal copy of the variable?

Comment: @Galik because it's not read-only. It's being modified in `myFunction`. And I can't make it local either because it's also used by other functions inherited from the base class.

Comment: You seem to be using a `mutex` lock to find the variable so you don't  have to lock it. Why not just lock the variable?

Comment: Because it takes much more time to work with it compared to `std::find/std::distance`.

Comment: This seems unusual. Are you sure different calling threads are using the same `MyClass` object shared between them? If that were true then I would expect them to synchronize access to your object. Otherwise I would expect the callers to have one of your objects per thread.